# Get File Structure from Get Metadata in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to get the column names for a parquet file. I have a Get Metadata module in my pipeline and it is using a parquet dataset with only the root folder provided. Because only the folder is provided ADF is not letting me get the file structure that contains the column names. The file name is not provided because that can change. Can anyone provide some advice on how to approach this?

Comment: I have this same challenge.  GetMetadata needs a MAJOR update.   In addition to this issue, not having recursive capability is a MAJOR hurdle that causes one to create function app for something that it already does (just doesn't do it recursively).  Most folks that I talk that leverage PARQUET point to a directory, because as you pointed out, you typically don't control the file names and just point at the root of the directory.

Answer (score 2):

You will need 2 `Get Metadata` activities and a `ForEach` activity to get the file structure if your file name is not the same every time.

**Source dataset:**

Parameterize the file name as the name changes frequently.

[image]

**Preview** of source data:

[image]

**Get Metadata1:**

- In the first `Get Metadata` activity, get the file name **dynamically**.
- You can also specify if your file name contains any specific **pattern** by adding an expression in the filename or you can mention **asterisk** (*) if you don’t have a specific pattern or need more than 1 file in the folder needs to be processed.
- Give field list as **child items** when you want to get the files from the folder.

[image]

**Output** of Get Metadata1: Get the file name from the folder.

[image]

**FoEach activity:**

Using the `ForEach` activity, you can get the item's name listed inside the Get Metadata activity output array.

[image]

**Get Metadata2:**

Add `Get Metadata` activity inside `ForEach` activity to get the file structure or column list of the current file from the folder. It can loop the number of items count in the folder (**1 or more**).

[image]

**Output** of Get Metadata2:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can parameterize your file name in dataset or via GetMeta data activity, get the list of files within the folder and then via GetMetaData activity get the list of columns for those corresponding files.